# Find C value given CDF

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, cumulative-distribution-functions

> Given $Y$ a continuous random variable which takes no values with positive probability. Let $F$ be its CDF given by the table:

$F(y)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
y<0 & C \log (1-y)/y\\ 
y>=0 & 1
\end{matrix}\right.$

Find the value of C.

I tried to get the probability i.e. $P(Y=0)$ from the corresponding CDF. $P(Y>=y)=1-P(Y<y)=1-C \log (1-y)/y$

$P(Y<y)=C \log (1-y)/y$

Thus $P(Y=y)=P(Y>=y)-P(Y<y)$

Equating this to $0$ and substituting the value of $y$ as $0$, I am finding the value of $C$.

But the answer is not coming correct. Can you please let me know if the approach to the above formulation is correct and at which step it is going wrong?

Comment: @AaronHendrickson No

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By assumption, $F$ is continuous at $0$. The right limit is $1$, while the left limit is $$\lim_{y\to 0^-}{\frac{C\log(1-y)}{y}}=C\lim_{y\to 0^-}{\frac{\log(1-y)}{y}}=C\cdot(-1)=-C.$$ Therefore, $-C=1$, which gives $C=-1$.

Besides, in your assumption, $Y$ takes no values with positive probability. There is no wonder why $P(Y=0)=0$.

Comment: Thank you. For continuous random variables CDF is always continuous and for discrete random variables it can be discontinuous?

Comment: In some sense, yes. For discrete r.v., it is not continuous, but always right-continuous.

Comment: Thanks but if i use the difference of the cdf as mentioned in the question description, i will disregard the cdf's continuity? Or is it possible to calculate it by using the difference of cdf at >=y and <y to get probability at point y=0 and then equating it to 0?

Comment: That is not correct. The formula $P(Y=y)=P(Y\geq y)-P(Y<y)$ is wrong. It should be $P(Y=y)=P(Y\geq y)-P(Y>y)$.

Comment: Thanks for the pointing the same. Here how can we use the difference of probabilities to calculate the probability at point y=0? P(Y>y)=1-P(Y<y)?

Comment: $P(Y>0)=1-P(Y\leq 0)=1-F(0)=1-1=0$ and $\displaystyle P(Y\geq 0)=1-P(Y<0)=1-\lim_{n\to\infty}{P(Y\leq -1/n)}=1-\lim_{n\to\infty}{F(-1/n)}=1-\lim_{n\to\infty}{\frac{C\log(1+1/n)}{-1/n}}=1+C$

Comment: Thus, $P(Y=0)=1+C-0=1+C$. By assumption, $Y$ takes no value with positive probability, so $1+C=0$, which gives $C=-1$ as well. (The calculation is not so trivial, so I do not recommend this approach personally.)

Comment: thank you. regarding y you assigned it with -1/n when it is less than 0?

Comment: No. It is based on the continuity of probability measure, something way beyond your current knowledge scope. That is also why I said I did not recommend this approach to you. Just remember the cdf is defined as $F(y)=P(Y\leq y)$ but NOT $P(Y<y)$, hence there is no elementary way to calculate $P(Y<0)$ directly.

Comment: Sure. Thank you. Can you please suggest references for the continuity of probability measure to start with?

Comment: It is not easy but worth trying: Theorem 1 in https://dspace.mit.edu/bitstream/handle/1721.1/73646/6-436j-fall-2005/contents/readings/l2.pdf. For more details: $A_n=\{Y\leq -1/n\}$ and $A=\{Y<0\}$. The sequence $A_n$ is increasing, i.e., $A_n\subseteq A_{n+1}$ for all $n$; and $A_n\to A$ as $n\to\infty$, so $\displaystyle P(Y<0)=P(A)=\lim_{n\to\infty}{P(A_n)}=\lim_{n\to\infty}{P(Y\leq -1/n)}=\lim_{n\to\infty}{F(-1/n)}$. Without this we cannot use the cdf $F$ directly.

Comment: Sure. Thank you.